# How to randomly pick a % of observations from a matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix, and I want to randomly pick 10% of the elements in the matrix, and store these elements into a dataframe indexing row, column and value.

I want to remark that I am interested in randomly sampling both row and column, so I am not interested in partial solutions to sample 10% of the rows and picking all the columns, or the other way around, sampling 10% of the columns and picking all the rows.

For example,

```
M = matrix(rnorm(30), 10, 3)
```

Given this matrix, that has 30 different elements, I would like to randomly sample 10% of them (0.1 * 30 = 3) and store those in a dataset of the form

```
row  column  value
 4     2      x
 7     1      x
 2     1      x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sample` from a vector from `seq_along` and get the row and column using `arrayInd` and `cbind` this with the value of the matrix.

```
i <- sample(seq_along(M), length(M) %/% 10)
cbind(arrayInd(i, dim(M)), M[i])
#cbind(arrayInd(i, dim(M), c("row", "column"), TRUE), value = M[i]) #Alternative with names
#     [,1] [,2]        [,3]
#[1,]    5    1 -0.72818419
#[2,]    9    1  1.14609041
#[3,]    2    2  0.01162598
```

Answer (score 0):

View the 2d matrix as a long 1d array,i.e. ravel it logically, not flattern it.
Then get 0.1 * len(matrix) * len(matrix[0]) rand numbers from 0 to len(matrix-1)*len(matrix[0]-1)

For example, you have a rand number: randVar,
then it can be represented in the form of `row and col`

```
row = randVar / len(matrix[0])  
col = randVar % len(matrix[0])
```